# How to display list of character devices and block devices separately

Tags: devices

How can I display list of character devices and block devices connected to my computer separately(List of only character devices or block devices at a time)
from sudo cat /proc/devices using shell script commands

I tried 
cat /proc/devices | head -n 38 for character devices but different computers have different numbers of character and block devices

Comment: I tried this:
sudo cat /proc/devices | head -n 38 for character devices
but different computers have different number of character and block devices

Comment: OK, please [edit] the question to mention that. People here like to see that you've made an effort. BTW, don't use `sudo` - it's not needed here.

Comment: ok, but do you have an answer to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character devices:

```
sed -n '/^Character/, /^$/ { /^$/ !p }' /proc/devices
```

Block devices:

```
sed -n '/^Block/, /^$/ { /^$/ !p }' /proc/devices
```

Explanation:

- `sed` - text **s**tream **ed**itor
- `-n` - don't implicitly print lines
- `/start/, /end/` - match from `start` line to `end` line
- `^` - start of line, `$` - end of line
- `{ /^$/ !p }` - print if line is not blank - This only affects the character devices section, but we might as well leave it in for the block devices.